# Prove that $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sqrt{\frac{1}{\left(x_{k}+1\right)^{2}}+\frac{x_{k+1}^{2}}{\left(x_{k+1}+1\right)^{2}}}\ge\frac{n}{\sqrt{2}}$

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series

For all $x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n}\ge0$, let $x_{n+1}=x_{1}$. Prove that
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sqrt{\frac{1}{\left(x_{k}+1\right)^{2}}+\frac{x_{k+1}^{2}}{\left(x_{k+1}+1\right)^{2}}}\ge\frac{n}{\sqrt{2}}$$

Since this sequence is of the form $\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+...$, I squared both sides to obtain $\sum_{\text{cyc}}^{ }a+2\sum_{\text{cyc}}^{ }ab$, and on substituting all of the terms under $\sum_{\text{cyc}}^{ }a$ appropriately and combining terms with a common denominator, I was able to get that $\sum_{\text{cyc}}^{ }a\ge\frac{n}{2}$.

$$\implies\sqrt{\sum_{\text{cyc}}^{ }a}\ge\sqrt{\frac{n}{2}}$$
However, I'm not able to proceed further. Could anyone help out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can employ the Minkowski inequality and the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to deal with your desire inequality.

Recall that the **Minkowski inequality** states that:
For any $a_{1},\ldots,a_{n},b_{1},\ldots,b_{n}$, we have
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n}\sqrt{a_{k}^2+b_{k}^2}\geq \sqrt{(\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k})^2+(\sum_{k=1}^{n}b_{k})^2}$$
As a result, we have
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n}\sqrt{\frac{1}{(x_k+1)^2}+\frac{x_{k+1}^{2}}{(x_{k+1}+1)^2}}\geq \sqrt{A^2+(n-A)^2}\geq \frac{n}{\sqrt{2}}, $$
where $A:=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{x_k+1}$, and the last inequality is due to the Cauchy-Schwarz ineqaulity.

Comment: Learned about the Minkowski inequality just now. Superb solution!